# Firebase - Cloud Firestore permissions

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 collections: one for the users and the other one for some images that the users upload. Every image has a reference to his owner.

I'm able to see all the images but when I logout I get

> Missing or insufficient permissions

To avoid this I'd have to change the permissions on my ddbb:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      // Allow requests from authenticated users
            allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

but is not that correct? (maybe I need to change my code also)

Comment: Do you want the images to be visible publicly?  If not, then it is correct that you have insufficient permissions after you've logged out.  You should also add permissions to prevent users from writing to the `/users` collection, unless it is with their own uid

Comment: No, the images must be visible for everyone. Yes, I also need to add that (do you know how to point to the document.ownerId also?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should allow anyone to view images, only authenticated users to write images and only the authenticated user can see their own data in the `/users` collection

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /images/{imageId} {
      // Allow reads from public
      // Allow writes from authenticated users
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null
                   && resource.data.ownerId == request.auth.uid;
    }
    match /users/{userId} {
      // Allow access from authenticated user
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is also possible to ensure that the `ownerId` field only contains the current `request.auth.uid`.  However, I'd recommend storing a `DocumentReference` here, rather than just the `uid`.  I've scoured the documentation and I can't work out how to do that.  I'll check and update my post.  In the meantime, I can update the answer to show the `uid` permission in the `ownerId` field

Comment: Wow, that's perfect thanks! I'll read about DocumentReference to use this instead the id. Cheers!

Comment: I'm getting same problem with permissions when I push content (logged) or when I try to get it

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that you're using to add the content and the error that you're returning?  Please ping me a comment, when it's done so I can take a look.

Comment: Have you added rules for the recipes collection?

Comment: I was going to comment you exactly that: the name was 'images' instead 'recipes'. My fault, sorry. That fixes the problem to display the images but still getting the other one when pushing. Looking into it

Comment: Don't forget that when pushing a new document, you need to have the `ownerId` field containing the same ID as the user pushing the document.  You could try commenting that rule to see if it is the one causing the issue.  The RTDB has a Rules Simulator.  I really hope that Cloud Firestore gets one soon.

Comment: Yes, was trying that and it works without `&& resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid`. I think we don't need to check that only that we have id (we're logged in). But we need to check this when we MODIFY that document.

Comment: also `allow delete: if resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;` would be nice

Comment: ok, trying with `update` and `delete` now. I'll update your answer as well if it works

Comment: perfect, working and updated question and answer. Please, double check that it's ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168236/discussion-between-jason-berryman-and-daniel-rodriguez).